# I use the following configuration in expressjs, how to use it in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

There will be errors when used directly in nestjs

```
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the middleware, and then apply the GET methods:

```
export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(YourMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.Get });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but it has achieved my goal.

```
  app.use((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      res.sendFile(
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'build', 'index.html'),
      );
    }
  });
```